# How to download VS Build Tools using curl

Tags: curl

I am typing to download a file using `curl` which I can download with a web browser via
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16.
I have tried `-L`, `-X POST`, `-X GET` and whatnot; nothing works though.
How I can download the file above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like first you will need to use `curl -L "https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16"` to get to the right place with the download link, and then from the response, extract the `<script>` which redirects to the actual download.

In the output of the last page you are redirected to, there is:

```
<script>var downloadResult = {result: 'success', downloadUrl: 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/{uuid}/{random_token}/vs_BuildTools.exe'};</script>
```

You'll need to extract the `downloadUrl` from that and then download that URL.